# No withdrawal from paypal to Egypt, Udemy.com requires paypal. What should i do?

Tags: paypal, withdrawal, egypt

I am a constructor at udemy.com and from Egypt but the problem is that the only way to get paid is trough paypal and paypal does not withdraw money to Egypt yet. Is there any other alternatives i can use, Maybe a specific institution that can help me ?

Comment: If the only way to get paid is through paypal, and if you cannot use paypal, you are logically out of luck. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: No you understand my question, But do you think there might be someone who i can use his paypal account to transfer money to him/her as then they send me that money over a bank-wire transfer ? Is there someone who takes such a thing as a job ? maybe call him self "Money Transfer" ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place for your question, but I looked at [the instructor terms and conditions at Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/terms/instructor/) and it mentions *"in US dollars, **via check** or PayPal".* Can you have Udemy send you a check, instead of using PayPal? It may be inconvenient, but inconvenient may be preferred to impossible.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I sent them an email and now waiting for their response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find a relative in another country who has the ability to receive PayPal, and have them transfer the money to you via Western Union or Hawala.

Comment: I am discussing some solutions with the uDemy company, and if it wont work out that would be the only solution, by then i will mark your answer as correct.